# Flutter: Ordering List in StringBuilder

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have a problem with ordering List by field 'expireDate'. I'm fetching data from the Google Firebase and use StreamBuilder and FutureBuilder for creating and filling the List.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeHAg.png)

Original code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('users/${widget.user.uid}/products')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {                                        
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var lst = new List(snapshot.data.documents.length);
                    lst[index] = snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID;
                    return ListTile(
                      title: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                          future:
                              snapshot.data.documents[index]['idProduct'].get(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {                           
                            return Center(
                              child: Card(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    ListTile(
                                      leading: Text(
                                        snapshot.data['expireDate'],
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      title: Text(
                                        snapshot.data['productName'],
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),                                  
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    );
                  });

        },
      ),
```

When I add .orderby it returns empty List

```
stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('users/${widget.user.uid}/products').orderby('expireDate')
            .snapshots(),
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of a document (in the Firestore console) that you'd expect to show up as the result of that second query?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot

Comment: Hmmm... that looks like it should work at first glance. Hopefully somebody else can spot what's going wrong.